# What maximum value I can set in the Session Lifetime field under global configuration of Joomla?

Tags: php, session, joomla

I want to know what maximum value I can set and joomla accept in the field Session Lifetime under global configuration. so that I can set the maximum acceptable value here.

I want to increase the session life time for frontend of joomla and I think this value must me under the maximum limit joomla accept.

see attached.
[image]

any idea..?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no maximum.  However, you don't want to set it too high, otherwise it'll never clear the sessions.  This will eat up space in your database.  It will also open you to a form of Denial-Of-Service attack where by simply generating new sessions you run out of disk space.  Keep it a sane time (I would say less than an hour or two).

Comment: why do you want a long session? Like ircmaxell noted are issues with having really long sessions. what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Brent:I want joomla session something like stackoverflow session never logout until they click to logout

Comment: I figured as much, that's a fairly common question and the session is not the way to do it. See below for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the core Joomla login module there is an option for "Remember Me". When the user selects that option they stay logged in until the click the logout button. You can do a couple of things if you want users to stay logged in, both can be done with a template override.

First, make a copy of JOOMLA INSTALL/modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php and place it in 
JOOMLA INSTALL/YOUR TEMPLATE/HTML/mod_login/default.php

Next, edit that new file. If you want to default the remember me as checked look near line 48 and change it to:

```
<input id="modlgn_remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes" alt="Remember Me" checked />
```

Or if you want users to automatically stay logged in without having an option to turn it off, look near line 48 and change it to:

```
<input id="modlgn_remember" type="hidden" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes" alt="Remember Me" checked />
```

That should fix your problem.